# sndroid maps v2 using json hashmap

Tags: android

how to start activity when click on marker with json and clustering
my map is already clustering but i cant start to new activity when click on marker without title

this is my code

```
package tmg.tower;

/**
 * Created by DIMAS on 25/06/2015.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private JSONParser json;
    private LatLng myLocation;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    Server serv = new Server();
    String conn = serv.connection();
    String url = conn + "********";
    JSONArray str_json = null;
    static final int showerror = 1;
    public static final String SP = "shareAt";
    SharedPreferences shareAt;
    public static final String KEY_LAT_TUJUAN = "lat_tujuan";
    public static final String KEY_LNG_TUJUAN = "lng_tujuan";
    static final LatLng AWAL = new LatLng(3.584695, 98.675079);
    Button mBtnFind;
    EditText etPlace;
    Button searchlist;
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LatLng myPosition;
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("GPS Disabled, Buka Setting dan Aktifkan GPS?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (cek_status(this)) {
            Server serv = new Server();
            conn = serv.connection();
            new getListInfo().execute();
        } else {
            showDialog(showerror);
        }

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment myMapFragment
                = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        myMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

        myMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(AWAL, 15));
        myMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        mBtnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
        etPlace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_place);
        searchlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
        searchlist.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting the place entered
                String location = etPlace.getText().toString();

                if(location==null || location.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Place is entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                String url = "https://**********";

                try {
                    // encoding special characters like space in the user input place
                    location = URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String siteid = "Site_ID=" + location;

                String sensor = "sensor=false";


                // url , from where the geocoding data is fetched
                url = url + siteid + "&" + sensor;

                // Instantiating DownloadTask to get places from Google Geocoding service
                // in a non-ui thread
                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading the geocoding places
                downloadTask.execute(url);



            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick (View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
                startActivity(i);
    }
    public boolean cek_status(Context cek) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) cek.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
            case showerror:
                AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                errorDialog.setTitle("Error Connection");
                errorDialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
                errorDialog.setNeutralButton("exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                                startActivity(exit);
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog errorAlert = errorDialog.create();
                return errorAlert;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);


            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;

    }


    /** A class, to download Places from Geocoding webservice */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            // Instantiating ParserTask which parses the json data from Geocoding webservice
            // in a non-ui thread
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }
    class getListInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading server...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(url);

            try {
                str_json = json.getJSONArray("tower");

                for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("Site ID", ar.getString("Site ID"));
                    map.put("Site Name", ar.getString("Site Name"));
                    map.put("Address", ar.getString("Address"));
                    map.put("Lattitude", ar.getString("Lattitude"));
                    map.put("Longitude", ar.getString("Longitude"));

                    dataMap.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getApplicationContext(), myMap);
            myMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataMap.size(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
                        map = dataMap.get(i);
                        mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(Double.parseDouble(map.get("Lattitude")), Double.parseDouble(map.get("Longitude"))));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            GeocodeJSONParser parser = new GeocodeJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a an ArrayList */
                places = parser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){


            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("Lattitude"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("Longitude"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("Site ID");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);


                // Locate the first location
                if(i==0)
                    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;
    TextView tvLocInfo;


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        myLocation = new LatLng(myMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), myMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        if (myLocation != null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LAT_TUJUAN, marker.getPosition().latitude);
            bundle.putDouble(KEY_LNG_TUJUAN, marker.getPosition().longitude);
            shareAt = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(SP, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shareAt.edit();
            String replace_string_first = marker.getTitle().replace(" ", "_");
            editor.putString("Site ID", replace_string_first);
            editor.putString("Lattitude", replace_string_first);
            editor.putString("Longitude", replace_string_first);
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.putExtra("Site ID", replace_string_first);
            intent.putExtra("Lattitude", replace_string_first);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", replace_string_first);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

how to get intent json object without marker.getTitle ?

thanks for help